# Incomplete type using typedef function pointer

Tags: c++, typedef, auto-ptr, boost-function, incomplete-type

I've got an abstract base class that defines an interface to data sinks.  Concrete implementations of data sinks are acquired via factories.  In an effort to tidy up code, I created a typedef for the factory method that returns new DataSink objects from within the DataSink abstract base class.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class DataSink
{
    public:
            DataSink() { }
            virtual ~DataSink() { }
            void Open(const std::string path)
            {
                    InternalOpen(path);
            }
            bool IsOpen()
            {
                    return InternalIsOpen();
            }
            void Write(const uint8_t* data, const size_t offset, const size_t size)
            {
                    InternalWrite(data, offset, size);
            }
            void Close()
            {
                    InternalClose();
            }

    protected:
            virtual void InternalOpen(const std::string path) = 0;
            virtual bool InternalIsOpen() = 0;
            virtual void InternalWrite(const uint8_t* data, const size_t offset, const size_t size) = 0;
            virtual void InternalClose() = 0;
};
typedef std::auto_ptr<DataSink>(*get_new_data_sink_function_type)(std::string);
```

If I then attempt to declare a:
`boost::function<get_new_data_sink_function_type> getNewDataSinkFunction_;`
somewhere down the road, I get:
`error: field 'getNewDataSinkFunction_' has incomplete type`
If I instead declare:
`boost::function<std::auto_ptr<DataSink>(std::string)> getNewDataSinkFunction_;`
...everything is fine.

I realize DataSink is an incomplete type because it is abstract, but because I'm using reference semantics due to the std::auto_ptr, that should be OK, right?  In any case, that doesn't explain why the typedef fails and the cut&paste of the typedef's definition succeeds.  Is this a quirk with boost::function?

Compiler is gcc 4.3.3.  Any insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `const` qualifiers on the `size_t` arguments really aren't needed, and removing them would make the code fit better in the question (without the horizontal scroll bar).

Comment: You are correct, as they are passed in by value.  `const` qualifying arguments that I know are `const` has become almost a reflex... got a little overzealous, there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_new_data_sink_function_type` is not a function type, but the type of a pointer to a function. `boost::function` requires a function type (or signature).

In addition, an abstract class need not be an incomplete type (and it's not at the site of your `typedef`). The 'incomplete type' part of the warning likely stems from the fact that `boost::function` is possibly written like this:

```
template<typename Sig>
class function; // Not defined!

template<typename Ret, typename Arg>
class function<Ret(Arg)> {
    // ...
};

// Various other specializations
```

which means that when `boost::function` is instantiated with a non-function type, as in your case, no specialization matches and the base template is selected. Since it is not defined, it is an incomplete type.

---

The simplest fix you can do is make your `typedef` a real function type, which would make its name not misleading anymore:

```
typedef std::auto_ptr<DataSink> get_new_data_sink_function_type(std::string);
```

Notice that with this, `get_new_data_sink_function_type*` is the same pointer to function type as it was previously.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I was actually unaware you could typedef a function signature like that; I thought you were limited to function pointers only.  I further confused myself by thinking this would be OK since `boost::function` objects can be assigned to regular function pointers that have compatible signatures... why I thought this would imply that the template arguments could be similarly substituted I can only blame on temporary insanity...